# Работа с файлами в паскале

Tags: поиск, pascal, файлы

Как в паскале реализовать поиск файла с заданным именем в данной директории(просматривая вложенные папки)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекурсивно через [FindFirst, FindNext](http://www.cyberforum.ru/pascal/thread77837.html)

Comment: А как перебирать не только файлы, но и директории?

Comment: так же тока анализировать на аттрибут(Directory = $10; {имя подкаталога}) Директории те же файлы